# Fill the data frame from the list of strings with split condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a list like this:

```
l=['-1.1430054,5.9142456,8.293411','-0.42156982,6.976654,8.832993','-0.024368286,5.3268127,10.694611',
'-0.09136963,3.1469574,13.665298']
```

Now I want to create a data frame form this list in a way that the first element splitted by comma, so that the data frame should look like

```
df
col1         col2         col3
-1.1430054   5.9142456    8.293411
-0.42156982  6.976654     8.832993
-0.024368286 5.3268127    10.694611
-0.09136963  3.1469574    13.665298
```

I have tried this code to do this,

```
df=pd.DataFrame(columns=['col1','col2','col3'])
for i in range(0,len(l)):
    temp_df=pd.DataFrame(columns=['col1','col2','col3'])
    temp_x=l[i].split(',')[0]
    temp_y=l[i].split(',')[1]
    temp_z=l[i].split(',')[2]
    temp_df['col1']=[temp_x]
    temp_df['col2']=[temp_y]
    temp_df['col3']=[temp_z]
    df=df.append(temp_df)
```

This gives the perfect result as I want, But I want to reduce the execution time,
Looking for any shortcut or pythonic way to reduce the execution time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Split the strings and construct the dataframe as:

```
pd.DataFrame(i.split(',') for i in l).add_prefix('col')

        col0       col1       col2
0    -1.1430054  5.9142456   8.293411
1   -0.42156982   6.976654   8.832993
2  -0.024368286  5.3268127  10.694611
3   -0.09136963  3.1469574  13.665298
```

Answer (score 1):

one more solution,

```
df=pd.DataFrame({"col":l})
print(df.col.str.split(',', expand=True))
```

O/P:

```
              0          1          2
0    -1.1430054  5.9142456   8.293411
1   -0.42156982   6.976654   8.832993
2  -0.024368286  5.3268127  10.694611
3   -0.09136963  3.1469574  13.665298
```